# Django csrf token uses

Tags: django, django-views, csrf, mobile-application, django-csrf

I am building a server api that will have mobile devices and javascript as the frontend. All the post request contain json encoded data. Now I am not sure if I should have the views csrf protected or not. And even if I do then will giving the csrf token to a mobile device app when it logs in, so that it can use it always be enough or has the csrf token need to generated and given everytime??

If you think I shouldn't protect the views than i would like to know if it would be safe enough??

Answer (score 0):

This is a good explanation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

You need to use CSRF tokens on any request that changes data. Simple non-mutative GETs do not require one.